# Doing a JOIN in LINQ in C#

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following C# code

```
List<User> users = User.FindAll();
List<Role> roles = Role.FindAll();
```

These are custom security related objects. The properties on the two objects are shown here:

```
User                       Role
----                       ----
UserId                     RoleId
UserName                   RoleName
RoleIds
```

I am trying to get create a new User object that will give me the RoleIds and RoleNames for each user. Essentially, I want a new User object that will look like this:

```
User
----
UserId
UserName
Roles (RoleId, RoleName)
```

I need to do this in memory. Currently, I have the following:

```
var results = (from user in users
               select new
               {
                 UserId = user.UserId,
                 UserName = user.UserName,
               });
```

However, I do not know how to add the `Roles` property such that only a list of Roles associated with each user are included. I do not know how to do a join with the `roles` variable. Is there a way to do this with LINQ? If so, how?

Comment: did you even google linq join?

Comment: How are the `RoleIds` stored in the user table?  This may be more of an architecture issue...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Where`

```
var results = (from user in users
           select new
           {
             UserId = user.UserId,
             UserName = user.UserName,
             Roles = roles.Where(r => user.RoleIds.Contains(r.RoleId)).ToList() 
           });
```

This assumes that `RoleIds` is in fact an array containing RoleIds. If that's not the case and it is, say, a comma separate string of RoleIds then you would need to `string.split` it first to create an array of role Ids and then `Contains` would have the expected behavior (i.e. not matching "1" against "10".

Comment: This code would cause issues in cases where numbers exist in the role name.  (all depending on how the RoleIds are stored)  For instance, say there were 10 roles with Ids of 1-10 in your Role list.  If the RoleIds field contains something like "5,Role1", the where clause would be satisfied by both role 1 and 5.  Alternately, if the RoleIds field contains "10,RoleWhatever", it would return roles 1 and 10.

Comment: Yes, depends on what `RoleIds` is. I was assuming an array since it's plural (i.e. already joined with a table containing userids and role ids) but if it's a comma separated string you would need to `string.split` it first.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try this:

Create a Class

```
  Public Class tblUser
    {
    public string UserId  {get; set;} 
    public string UserName  {get; set;} 
    public string RoleIds {get; set;} 
    public string RoleName {get; set;}                   
    }

var results = (from h in users
               join  n Role on h.RoleIds  equal  n.RoleId
                 select new tblUser
                  {
                    UserId = h.UserId,
                    UserName = h.UserName,
                    RoleName  = n.RoleName 
                  }
               );
```

Hope it will help !!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

What I would suggest is this:  Refactor your User/Role relationship in the database so that you have three tables.

```
User
-----
UserId
UserName


Role
-----
RoleId
RoleName


UsersInRoles
-----
UserId
RoleId
IsActive
```

Then, have foreign key relationships from UsersInRoles to User and UsersInRoles to Role on the Id columns.  Then, when you query, you can join all three tables together to get the necessary information, like so:

```
var results = (from u in Users
               join uir in UsersInRoles on u.UserId equals uir.UserId
               join r in Role on uir.RoleId equals r.RoleId
               where uir.IsActive
               select new
               {
                   UserId = u.UserId,
                   UserName = u.UserName,
                   RoleName  = r.RoleName
               });
```